# C++ - Possible to omit parameters of type T in the methods of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I've got the following templated class:

```
template<class A>
class AssetFactory
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Asset> CreateAsset(const AssetDescriptor& assetDescriptor, const A& args) = 0;
};
```

In some derived classes of `AssetFactory<A>`, I don't need the `args` parameter, so I'd like to have a variant of `CreateAsset` without it, **using the same templated class**, meaning something like:

```
class DerivedAssetFactory : AssetFactory<???>
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Asset> CreateAsset(const AssetDescriptor& assetDescriptor) override;
};
```

My current solution is to define a template specialization using `void` to indicate "an AssetFactory with no arguments", like so:

```
template<>
class AssetFactory<void>
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Asset> CreateAsset(const AssetDescriptor& assetDescriptor) = 0;
};
```

Then, my derived class can inherit from `AssetFactory<void>` if they don't need the `args` parameter.

I'm wondering if this is usually the way to go for that kind of problem of if I should review my design ?

Thank you!

Comment: WHich is the purpose of `AssetFactory<T>`? Why `virtual` method, why template class?

Comment: My factories are stored in a vector and are identified using the type_index of A, which I've not demonstrated in my post since I wanted to removed as much noise as possible.

I can do something like that `AssetManager.CreateAsset<SomeArgs>({...})` and the manager will find the corresponding factory and call `CreateAsset<SomeArgs>(args)` on it.

Comment: `template<class ... Ts> class AssetFactory` might be more appropriate. so no specialization, empty pack for nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, didn't know about parameter pack. This'll definitely be useful!

Comment: You might also be interested by [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with `template<class ... Ts> using AssetFactory = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Asset>(const AssetDescriptor&, Ts...)>;`